# How to compare 2 massive/huge/long lists and output any non matching results in one field

Tags: excel, comparison

I have 2 massive columns filled with studentids

Column 1(SID)  has 110,000 rows

Column 2(SID2) has 100,000 rows

How do I make a check of column 1 = column 2 or vice versa and then finally place it all in one field!

### Current Results

```
SID SID2 
45  45
142 142
237 218
238 441  
410 410
440 442 
452 237
    452
```

### Final Expected output

```
SID SID2  Check
45  45
142 142
237 218
238 441   238,441
410 410
440 442   440
452 237
    452
          238,441,440
```

As you can see, all the ids that dont match should be placed in one field so I can easily spot them rathen than looking though 100,000 rows

Comment: Are you trying to see if a given SID (Column A) fails to match it's direct correspondent in Column B (so testing does A2=B2), or are you trying to see if Column A SIDs fail to match ANYTHING in Column B SID2? These result in two different answers. The fact that your Check column shows 2 formats leads me to believe that you're testing the latter scenario (ANY matches, not the 1to1 matches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SolarMike answered assuming that the test is A2=B2, but I think you're asking if A2=[Anything in Column B] and if B2=[Anything in Column A]. Here's how I'd test that:
[image: Testing multiple ranges against each other]

Column C:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)>1,"",A2),A2)
```

Column D:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)>1,"",B2),B2)
```

Column E (very crude, but effective):

```
=IF(AND(C2="",D2=""),"",CONCATENATE(C2,",",D2,","))
```

Now, your real problem is getting it all into one single cell. The only way I know how to do this is to use Concatenate, but it requires you to select EACH CELL individually.

```
=CONCATENATE(E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9,E10)
```

For 10000 rows, that doesn't seem feasible. Also, that output isn't very flexible, but I digress.

If you want to concatenate everything together in one cell, you have two options.

A)  Use the VBA code here (it's pretty simple, this seems like a viable option): [Concatenate Excel Ranges with VBA](https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/)

B) Hope that you have Office 365 with TEXTJOIN()  [See Support article here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Comment: your correct I will make that clear in the question!

Answer (score 0):

You could use match() with iferror() and if():

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B1,)>0,0),"ok",A1)
```

see:
[image]

To get both fields back use:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B1,)>0,0),"ok",A1)&" , "&IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B1,)>0,0),"ok",B1)
```